# How to use async and await inside a map function for sequential executing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Hi for me async and await is quiet new .I have function call which requires await method so as a result i need to use async and await.
I'm getting the values but they are not in order.

Below is my async and await map function

```
items.map(async (item) =>{
const itemx = await  
   Promise.all([w.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef).getItem()]);
  var likes = await Promise.all(itemx.getLikedByInformation());
  const comments = await Promise.all(itemx.comments.get());      
  articles[i].likecount = likes.likeCount
  articles[i].commentcount = comments.length
  articles[i].FileRef = item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef
  newst.push(articles[i++])
  })
```

Any suggestion will really be helpful

Comment: ` but they are not in order` means?? About which order you are talking about?

Comment: what is scope of  i and j. And what are they.

Comment: Where is this variable `i` coming from and why are you incrementing `j`?

Comment: I have declared an array outside and i'm getting those values inside the array . The articles is an array of objects i'm appending the new values to it from the values i got from async and await calls

Comment: That's actually a lot of code to sift through for (what I assume) is a rather simple question. Admittedly, more code than I personally am willing to read and understand. 

It's always good (in the very first place: for yourself!) to reduce a problem to its essentials: show as little code as possible, which of course still contains everything needed to understand your problem.

I often find myself doing this before asking something, and finding the solution myself in the process.

Comment: @panepeter I have corrected, can you please find the solution now?

Comment: @user8535404 I see you already have your answer. Still, thanks for cleaning your code up! The way it looks now is just **so** much easier to read and understand … that's a lot more attractive to people trying to help out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to await promises of the map function to get results in order.

```
async function main() {
  const items = []; // Fill your items
  const articles = []; // Fill your articles

  // Async map function return promise for each item
  const promises = items.map(async (item, i) => {
    console.log(item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef);
    const itemx = await Promise.all([
      w.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef).getItem()
    ]);

    console.log(item);
    var likes;
    likes = await Promise.all(itemx.getLikedByInformation());
    console.log("like " + likes.likeCount);
    const comments = await Promise.all(itemx.comments.get());
    console.log("Comments Count " + comments.length);

    // Create new object by appending articles[i],likes,comments
    return {
      ...articles[i],
      likecount: likes.likeCount,
      commentcount: comments.length,
      FileRef: item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef
    };
  });

  // Here you have everything in order.
  const newst = await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Each map item function runs asynchronously so there is no guarantee of order inside the map function, but you can return value from the map function which can be resolved to an ordered array by using `await  Promise.all()` since the promise array returned by the map function is in the correct order.

Answer (score -2):

try Promise.mapSeries for Sequential access with async await.

```
 async function main() {

 const items = []; // Fill your items
  const articles = []; // Fill your articles

  await Promise.mapseries( items, async (item, i) => {
    const itemx = await      

 Promise.all([w.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef).getItem()]);


  console.log(item);
  var likes
  likes = await Promise.all(itemx.getLikedByInformation());
 console.log("like " + likes.likeCount);
  const comments = await Promise.all(itemx.comments.get());
  console.log("Comments Count " + comments.length);


  //articles[i] = articles[i]+likes+comments
  articles[i].likecount = likes.likeCount
  articles[i].commentcount = comments.length
  articles[i].FileRef = item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef
  console.log(articles[i])

  newst.push(articles[i++])
  console.log(newst)
  j++
  })
```

Comment: I'm using react , I tried your code but getting this error => " Property 'mapseries' does not exist on type 'typeof Promise'"

Comment: `Promise.mapSeries` is part of the [bluebird library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) (or other libs as well, who knows …), but not part of any ES standard. If you refer to functions from libraries, please say so, because otherwise people testing your code will get errors.